# How to use purrr to simulate data?

Tags: r, loops, iteration, purrr

I have a table looking more or less like this:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 7.5 |
| 3 | 12.7 |

I would now like to take every y and put it as mean in `rnorm()` with whatever var to generate, let's say, 100 values. I want to do that for every x. In the end, I would like to have a new table, basically the same as above but with the generated numbers in y and x showing if y belongs to 1, 2, or 3. I know this is possible with purrr, but I've never done it before.

I hope somebody can help.

Cheers

My actual data frame is way longer, so it wouldn't make much sense to do everything by hand and then join them together later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can `map()` over `y` and then unnest:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# original data
d <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(5, 7.5, 12.7))

d |> 
  mutate(y = map(y, rnorm, n = 100)) |> 
  unnest(y)
#> # A tibble: 300 × 2
#>        x     y
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1  3.32
#>  2     1  3.78
#>  3     1  4.26
#>  4     1  4.03
#>  5     1  5.89
#>  6     1  5.31
#>  7     1  3.57
#>  8     1  2.64
#>  9     1  4.10
#> 10     1  5.60
#> # … with 290 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer above doesn't work; it seems like `map()` takes the first value and generates three datasets with it.

So this here works now for me:

```
d <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(5, 7.5, 12.7)) %>%
mutate(y = map(y, ~rnorm(100, .x, 2))) %>% 
unnest(y)
```

Comment: The only thing that should be different about your code is that you have specified the standard deviation to be `2` instead of the default of `sd  = 1`. Except of course, I did not assign the result. Did that confuse you? The `tidyverse` is generally free of side effects, I did not assign it to have it print to console. But if you want to go on using the data frame, it must be assigned